# on a Wordpress site, how is this URL able to display a pdf file even though there's not .pdf extension in the URL?

Tags: wordpress, url, permalinks

I have a Wordpress website running locally with URLs like this:
localhost/mysite/wp-content/pdf/products/drawing

when I go there it displays a file called drawing.pdf stored at /mysite/wp-content/pdf/products/

BUT, same URL on my live site: 
mysite.com/wp-content/pdf/products/drawing
does not work, showing: Page Not Found Error 404
If I do this, it works:
mysite.com/wp-content/pdf/products/drawing.pdf

Do you have any idea why my local site URLs work without being precise about the .pdf extension? Obviously I missed/changed some settings on my live site. But I do not know what it is. I check Permalinks, both offline and live sites are set to "post name".

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I fixed this looking out in the database the post that has the slug "drawing" and changed it to drawing-2. try that. in the table wp_posts

Comment: Miguel: would you mind clarifying this?

Comment: Sure, when you create a Post Object can be a page a post or CPT you save a slug that is a unique app word like this example drawing. Mysite.com/drawing is the slug of the Post type. Go to the database and search in the table WP_post for post_name = drawing

Comment: Thanks Miguel. I see what you mean now. However that is not applicable to my situation. These URL are not posts. Rather, they appear on a post. Meaning I go to this page and it displays several icon:
icon1 has this URL: localhost/mysite/wp-content/pdf/products/drawing
which if I click on, will serve me file drawing.jpg

A slug would be irrelevant in this case, right?

Comment: mysite.com is the homepage? do you have redirect plugin?

Comment: Mysite.com is the homepage. No redirect plugin that I know off. I turned them all of to debug anyway

Comment: Did you update the permalinks?

Comment: I did. Just did again. No effect.

Comment: Try uploading other file there and do that, with just comments its difficult to debug this.